# how to change the labels list in agglomerative cluster?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to implement agglomerative clustering algorithm from scratch in python but I don't know how can I change the label list value after calculate the distance matrix
here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import math
class AgglomerativeClustering:
    def __init__(self, n_clusters=2):
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        
    def fit(self, X):
        n_samples = X.shape[0]
        self.labels_ = np.arange(n_samples)
        n_clusters = n_samples
        
        
        distance_matrix = self._single_linkage(X)
        print("before whule loop")
        print(distance_matrix)
        while n_clusters > self.n_clusters:
            # Find the closest pair of clusters
            i, j = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(distance_matrix), distance_matrix.shape)
            print(n_clusters-self.n_clusters)
            # Merge the closest pair of clusters
            
            self.labels_[self.labels_ == j] = i
            n_clusters -= 1
            
            # Update the distance matrix
            
            for k in range(n_samples): 
                
                if(i==k):
                  distance_matrix[i, j]=math.inf
                else:
                  
                  distance_matrix[i, k] = min(distance_matrix[i, k], distance_matrix[j, k])
                  distance_matrix[k, i] = distance_matrix[i, k]


                
                
            distance_matrix = np.delete(distance_matrix, j, axis=0)
            distance_matrix = np.delete(distance_matrix, j, axis=1)
            print(self.labels_)
            print(distance_matrix) 
            n_samples=n_samples-1
        
        self.labels_ = self.labels_.astype(np.int) 
        
        return self
    
    def _single_linkage(self, X):
        n_samples = X.shape[0]
        distance_matrix = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))
        for i in range(n_samples):
            for j in range( n_samples):
                if(i==j):
                  distance_matrix[i, j]=math.inf
                else:
                  distance_matrix[i, j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((X[i] - X[j])**2))
                  distance_matrix[j, i] = distance_matrix[i, j]

                
        return distance_matrix
```

the problem is in the labels list which i need to update it with every new distance calculation but I'm stuck in this part

any idea can help me please